# change date format on json format

Tags: php, json, ajax

> I want to change date format in json when i bind the result .
>
> My script

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      async: false,
      url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>admin/get_mail_contents",
      data: datastring,
      cache: false,
      success: function (result) {
          alert(result);
          var result = $.parseJSON(result);
          console.log(result.from);                                    
          $('#content').html('');
          $("#content").append('<div class="mail-toolbar clearfix"> </div><div class="divider"></div><div class="pad5A clearfix mrg10B"> <i class="glyph-icon icon-clock-o mrg5R"></i> ' + result['0']['start_time'] + ' , ' + result['0']['start_date'] + '</div></div> </div>');
      }
});
```

> My actual out put is  15:37:00 , 2017-07-25 and i want to print 15:37 , 25-07-2017 in view how to change in json .

Comment: `result['0']['start_time']` is stored data right

Comment: You just change date format for `insert`

Comment: we can not change in json , i tried like date('d-m-Y',strtotime(result['0']['start_time'])); i already tried this in other page and it work but if i use it in json it not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var d = new Date(result['0']['start_date'] +' '+ result['0']['start_time']);

console.log(d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes());

console.log((d.getDate()) + '-' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' +  d.getFullYear());
```

Comment: ok for time it work perfectly but now i want to show date like 25-07-2017 how can i get, i use d.getDate() but it only return 25(mean current date only)

Comment: i think result['0']['start_time'] has the date you want so can directly use that

Comment: no i use  result['0']['start_time'] for time and  result['0']['start_date'] for date ,i use two field for date and time in my table.

Comment: yes i use your answer for time ,and result['0']['start_date'] also return 2017-07-25 but i want d-m-Y format 25-07-2017 how i get

Comment: i follow your answer it only return year and i add likeconsole.log(d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + 1 + '-' + d.getDate() + '-' + d.getMonth() + '-' + d.getFullYear()); but in place of month it return 6 but in my table it has 7

Comment: see my answer it must be (d.getMonth() + 1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150157/discussion-between-arun-kumaresh-and-dipti).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try moment.js from https://momentjs.com/

It's easy to use to transform your formatted date to another formatting

Here's what I tried on my browser console

```
$.getScript("moment.js");
dt = new Date("15:37:00 , 2017-07-25");
moment(dt).format("HH:mm , DD-MM-YYYY");
```

and it will output as something like this:

```
"15:37 , 25-07-2017"
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use split function to create array of your date then rearrange values then create string from that array

```
 var date_array=result['0']['start-date'].split('-');
 var date_string=date_array[2].'-'.date_array[1].'-'.date_array[0];
```

Then use the date_string instead of result['0']['start_date']